# Error publishing PostGIS Layer to Geoserver using Python gsconfig

Tags: python, geoserver-rest-api, gsconfig

I can't seem to publish a geoserver layer from our postgis database.

When running a basic script it trips on this line:

```
ft = cat.publish_featuretype(name=tableP, store=ds, native_crs='EPSG:{}'.format(tableEpsg), 
                            srs='EPSG:{}'.format(tableEpsg), jdbc_virtual_table=None, native_bbox=None)
```

I get an error below.

```
Store: <geoserver.store.DataStore object at 0x000001FA23C7EE08>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\GIS\Tools\06. QGIS\Geoserver\gs Test (2).py", line 132, in <module>
    ft = cat.publish_featuretype(name=tableP, store=ds, native_crs='EPSG:{}'.format(tableEpsg), srs='EPSG:{}'.format(tableEpsg), jdbc_virtual_table=None, native_bbox=None)  #
  File "C:\PythonEnvironments\Python37x64\lib\site-packages\geoserver\catalog.py", line 716, in publish_featuretype
    headers=headers, params=params)
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'params' referenced before assignment
```

I don't see 'params' as a parameter of the 'cat.publish_featuretype' method but to be honest I'm struggling to find detailed documentation. So why does that come up, or what is the real error?

I read on a [github page](https://github.com/planetfederal/gsconfig/issues/99) it could be related to the bbox, so I added that the value below as the 'native_bbox':
{'minx': 671198.619943575, 'maxx': 676473.914171803, 'miny': 2732715.24096015, 'maxy': 2736892.48917506, 'crs': 'EPSG:32638'}
But perhaps that was just a suggestion. I don't really know what the syntax of the 'native_bbox' should be. I also tried minx,maxx,miny,maxy,crs - same result.

All the examples online don't require you to put in the native_bbox.  Perhaps there is another parameter I need to specify in 'cat.publish_featuretype':

It's worth mentioning that I can successfully create a data store using the code, so it does connect ok and authenticate.

Here is the base code:

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog

geoservP = 'GeoserverURL/geoserver/rest/'
username='username' # changed
password='password' # changed

wspaceP = "ProjectName"
storeP = "StoreName"

databaseP = "databaseName"
dbTypeP = "postgres"
hostP = "our.sql.server"
userP = "dbuser"
passP = "dbpass"

schemaP = "o7_environment"
tableP = "parkpoly_omr_dsgn"
tableEpsg = 32638

# Create Catalog Object
cat = Catalog(geoservP, username, password)
print("Catalog: {}".format(cat))

# Create New Datastore Object
ds = cat.create_datastore(storeP,wspaceP)
ds.connection_parameters.update(host=hostP, port='5432', database=databaseP, user=userP, passwd=passP, dbtype='postgis', schema=schemaP)
cat.save(ds)
print("Saved new Store: {}".format(storeP))

# if already created just open the existing one as a store object
##ds = cat.get_store(storeP)
##print("Store: {}".format(ds))

ft = cat.publish_featuretype(name=tableP, store=ds, native_crs='EPSG:{}'.format(tableEpsg), srs='EPSG:{}'.format(tableEpsg), jdbc_virtual_table=None, native_bbox=None)
cat.save(ft)
print("Published Table: {}".format(tableP))
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That is one of the bugs I proposed a [fix for a while back](https://github.com/quadratic-be/gsconfig-py3/pull/3) - You might be better off using [my fork](https://github.com/ianturton/gsconfig-py3). However, given the lack of progress being made fixing things on any of the forks out there it might be best to consider the project essentially dead.

Comment: You nailed it!  thanks for the fork. I can now publish postgis layers, not requiring anything beyond the example code. For anyone else finding this, I replaced the original file '..\Python37x64\Lib\site-packages\geoserver\catalog.py' with Ian's version.  I just hope my next step of saving and setting symbology will be nice and easy....