# Error publishing PostGIS layer to GeoServer using Python gsconfig library

Tags: python, postgis, geoserver-rest-api, gsconfig

I am unable to publish a PostGIS table as a GeoServer layer using the gsconfig library. I was able to create a workspace, data store but was unable to publish layers in the store.

While running the script it gives an error on this line

```
layer1 = cat.publish_featuretype(name = self.tablename, store = schema_store, native_crs='EPSG:4326', srs='EPSG:4326')
```

The error is as shown below

```
File "S:\Coding\Python\sz_env\lib\site-packages\gsconfig_py3-1.0.7-py3.9.egg\geoserver\catalog.py", line 716, in publish_featuretype
headers=headers, params=params)   UnboundLocalError: local variable 'params' referenced before assignment
```

I am unable to figure out the error. Found a similar issue in the below link.

[Error publishing PostGIS Layer to Geoserver using Python gsconfig](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/394564/error-publishing-postgis-layer-to-geoserver-using-python-gsconfig/421605#421605)

I tried Ian's version as mentioned in the above link but got an import error. ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'urllib'

```
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module File "S:\Coding\Python\sz_env\lib\site-packages\gsconfig_py3-1.0.8-py3.9.egg\geoserver\catalog.py", line 21, in <module> File "<frozen zipimport>", line 259, in load_module File "S:\Coding\Python\sz_env\lib\site-packages\gsconfig_py3-1.0.8-py3.9.egg\geoserver\layergroup.py", line 4, in <module> ImportError: cannot import name 'url' from 'urllib'
```

Comment: did you add `urlib` to your enviroment?

Comment: Yes, urllib is present in the environment. In fact, it is showing as below while installing your fork.                                                                                                                                              "Using s:\coding\python\sz_env\lib\site-packages
Searching for urllib3==1.26.2
Best match: urllib3 1.26.2
Adding urllib3 1.26.2 to easy-install.pth file"

Comment: However, it is urllib3 not urllib. I am not sure whether it would make a difference